# Which one is the best bonding mode for multiple wi-fi interfaces in a low quality wi-fi network

Tags: wireless-networking

I use 3 wi-fi adapters as bonding interface (two b/g and one ac) in my incredibly bad university network (which I cannot modify, of course) and I've been wondering which bonding mode is the best. Concrete questions that I had/have:

- Is it useful to choose backup because the three (or more - I think the ac adapter has three on it's own) antennas might suffer from extended interference due to the short distance (positioned on the left and on the right side of 15'' laptop and somewhere inside)? Which other mode would be best?
- Is it a problem to use different standards b/g and ac for the same bonding interface?. Should the ac adapter set to be the primary interface because it has probably the best connection. How would one do this?

As there's no such definition of an "incredibly bad network" let me elaborate on this:

- It takes sometimes > 10 min to get an IP address with `dhclient` for both the bonding and the individual interfaces
- in regular intervals 90 to 100 % package loss for over 1 minute
- further information, including benchmarks can be provided (I don't know them and would have to learn them), please comment

I'm connecting with

```
ifup wlan0 &
ifup wlan1 &
ifup wlan2 &
ifup bond0 &
dhclient -4 -v -w bond0
```

and `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface main inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface bond0 inet manual
    down ifenslave -d bond0 wlan0 wlan1 wlan2
    bond-mode 3
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-slaves wlan0 wlan1 wlan2

allow-bond0 wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
    bond-master bond0

allow-bond0 wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
    bond-master bond0

allow-bond0 wlan2
iface wlan2 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
    bond-master bond0

iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm deeply familiar with 802.11 even at the lowest levels, and I don't see how any bonding mode could possibly work on a multi-AP network you don't control.

At least not without a special WNIC/driver that can do proxy authentications and associations for each MAC address in the bond group.

Most of the bonding modes, including broadcast mode (3) which you seem to be trying, even in a simple wired Ethernet case, require special switch configuration.

Some modes that don't require special switch configuration, such as active-backup, balance-tlb and balance-alb, require that you be able to send or receive frames with an arbitrary MAC address on any interface, which runs afoul of 802.11's requirement that each wireless client station (that is, each client MAC address) must 802.11-Authenticate and 802.11-Associate with the AP before the AP will allow data traffic to and from that MAC address. That's why I mentioned needing a special WNIC/driver that can do 802.11 Auth's and Assoc's on behalf of the bond0 MAC address and other slave MAC addresses.

My sense of this is that link-level (Ethernet / 802.11-level) bonding is not going to be the solution for you. Help your IT department diagnose and fix their network.

Comment: Then I experienced an enormous placebo effect, especially the ac adapter seemed to contribute to a much steadier connection. How can I check whether my devices (don't) "802.11-Authenticate and 802.11-Associate with the AP" or is it sure that they don't if they don't have a "special WNIC/driver" (maybe they have)? Controll LEDs on both device (internal doesn't have one) are both showing activity.

Comment: Can you measure the difference between the 802.11ac adapter alone vs. in bonded mode?

Comment: I checked the issue with the network administrator who has expressed the same scepticism as @Spiff, the qualitity of the working connection is about 100 to 1000 times better than be before, so needs no measuring, I guess. Thanks for your answer!